# Problem with MySQL while using 'WITH' clause to manage hierachical data

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-18.04, mysql-error-1064, with-clause

I am having a hard time getting the following query to work correctly. I feel like I have everything set up correctly. I read that earlier versions of MySQL Workbench did not support 'with'. I updated Ubuntu and am running MySQL Workbench 8.0.20. However, when I try to use the 'with' clause, MySQL keeps telling me that with is not valid at the position for the server version. The goal is to list my data in a hierarchical fashion. For this I am using one table with TestCat_2 as my primary key and a Parent_id. I haven't really done a query like this before so I hope it is just something simple I am missing. For an example of what I am trying to accomplish, I will post the URLs of two blogs I was trying to follow. I would like to display the whole tree. Otherwise, if anyone could help me find a workaround I would appreciate it.

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-adjacency-list-tree/

https://www.akki.io/blog/mysql-adjacency-list-model-for-hierarchical-data-using-cte/

My Query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE category_path (TestCat_2, TestCat2_name, path) as

(

select TestCat_2, TestCat2_name, TestCat2_name as path
from TestCat
where Parent_id is null

union all

select t.TestCat_2, t.TestCat2_name, concat(tp.path, ' > ', t.TestCat2_name)
from category_path as tp join TestCat as t 
on tp.TestCat_2 = t.Parent_id

)

select TestCat_2, TestCat2_name, path from category_path 
order by path;
```

[image: Session Tab]

Comment: I updated your question to show the query image, but you should rather include the text of the query, instead of an image. This way we can copy it out and test it in our environments. Check also the version of the server with which you are connected (see the Session tab in the lower left corner of the SQL IDE screen).

Comment: Thanks Mike, I made the adjustments to my post you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a MySQL server which supports this language construct. [Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) (CTE) were introduced in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the server version. I updated the server to 8.0, so the query should work now. I am trying to start the server, but am getting an error that says unable to connect to localhost:3306 (2003). I tried using the command line to start the server as well, but no luck. Otherwise, I haven't changed anything since updating.